# How to wget url like this `https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/0.8.2.1/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1.tgz` on CentOS 7

Tags: docker, centos, apache-kafka

Basic environment:

```
[root@0b3608de9c84 tmp]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
```

I want to install Kafka in Dockerfile,below is my Dockerfile instruction:

```
#choose scala and kafka version
ENV KAFKA_VERSION="0.8.2.1" SCALA_VERSION="2.11"

#install kafka
RUN cd /tmp && wget https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/$KAFKA_VERSION/kafka_$SCALA_VERSION-$KAFKA_VERSION.tgz && tar xf kafka_${SCALA_VERSIO    N}-${KAFKA_VERSION}.tgz -C /opt && rm kafka_${SCALA_VERSION}-${KAFKA_VERSION}.tgz
```

I know `https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/$KAFKA_VERSION/kafka_$SCALA_VERSION-$KAFKA_VERSION.tgz`(or https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/0.8.2.1/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1.tgz) is not true resource address.Can you help me use wget and the URL on Kafka web page to install Kafka correctly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking questions, you should always include the exact command you're using along with its error message and log file entry (if applicable). Otherwise, answerers like me are simply guessing based on limited information. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you’ve pointed out, https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/0.8.2.1/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1.tgz is not the real address. Instead, it links to a mirror site that is close to your location, e.g., I live in Ireland so `ftp.heanet.ie` is the closest mirror to my location.

You should (manually) use the URL of the relevant mirror site in your `wget` command, e.g.

```
wget http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/www.apache.org/dist/kafka/0.8.2.1/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1.tgz
```

The other issue is the spaces within the shell variable of your `tar` command:

```
tar xf kafka_${SCALA_VERSIO    N}-${KAFKA_VERSION}.tgz
```

Combining the above fixes should give you something similar to:

```
RUN cd /tmp && wget http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/www.apache.org/dist/kafka/$KAFKA_VERSION/kafka_$SCALA_VERSION-$KAFKA_VERSION.tgz && tar xf kafka_${SCALA_VERSION}-${KAFKA_VERSION}.tgz -C /opt && rm kafka_${SCALA_VERSION}-${KAFKA_VERSION}.tgz
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It is my first question on StackOverFlow and my English is poor.I have  noticed that the address `links to a mirror site that is close to your location`. In order to find the real links I go to the mirrors page and got it.

Comment: That's fine. We try to help new users (who are willing to learn) to use the site better. If my answer helped you, it would be good if you upvote /  [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer.